# Statistically comparing distributions with small sample sizes (for dummies)

Tags: distributions, small-sample

Please assume, safely, that I know next to nothing about statistics. I do not have statistical computer programs and rely primarily on Excel, online calculators, and the good graces of smarter friends.

I am trying to compare distributions with generally small sample sizes, in the context of archaeological sites. For example, one analysis is looking at differences in the size of houses (i.e., floor area). Site A might have 10 houses, each with a known floor area. Site B might have 6 houses, each with a known floor area. If I assume that house size correlates with some form of inequality, what is the best method to compare such distributions? I initially used means and t-tests (via Excel). I also provided standard deviations (Excel) and Gini coefficients (online calculator) to give some indication of intra-site variability, acknowledging that variability could affect the sites' means.

Any dumbed-down advice would be sorely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "*I do not have statistical computer programs*" -- there's some excellent free statistical software available, some primarily menu-driven, others primarily command driven, some very widely used, so there's really no reason for you to limit yourself to Excel. Indeed, just for an example, I carry R on a USB (from which it will run without any additional installation), so any PC that will allow me to run an executable at all is one I can do sophisticated statistical analysis on.

Comment: Thank you, Glen.  I was under the impression that such programs were fairly expensive.  I'll look into the free ones.  I appreciate the head's up.

Answer (score 1):

When data is continuous, a good method to compare the means is the t-test between two normal distributions.  A good method to compare the variances is the F-test for equality of variance between two normal distributions. These two methods are based on an assumption of normality which is hard to disprove for such small sample sizes. A priori, we might suspect that the distributions are scewed in a way that is not like the normal distribution. [Transforming the data](http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/tips-recognizing-and-transforming-non-normal-data/) and doing the analysis on the transformed data might help. With house sizes I would presume that a log-transform is good if one or some houses are a lot larger than other.

One could also take a more careful approach using, say [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) but the interpretation of a rejected hypothesis is more complex in the rank-framework.

When the sample size is this small, mean and variance is often the only meaningful information we can extract and hence compare meaningfully.

To conclude, I believe the F-test and T-test are best here and you should consider transforming data beforehand.

Comment: "*A good method to compare the variances is the F-test for equality of variance*" ... if you mean the variance-ratio test, this test is very definitely not robust to even moderate deviation from the normality assumption; it's unusual to see people recommend it these days. When you say "rank tests will not be rejected as often" ... what are the circumstances you're assuming, and why? (it's not like anyone actually has normality for example)... ctd

Comment: ctd... Just as an example, if you compare a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney to a t-test, one doesn't need more than a tiny bit of additional heavy tailedness (a fairly small amount of moderate contamination, say) before it has better power than the t-test; even at the normal the power curves tend to be *very* close. Indeed, if one wishes to buy a little insurance against drastic *loss* of power, that *rank* test is a very good deal.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong; the power of rank tests are in fact not worse than the t-test in general. So I have changed the answer.